# Why is this SqlTransaction rolling back upon closing the connection AFTER the transaction has been Committed?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlclient

I have a series of inserts inside of a transaction, followed by a commit.  If I query the database with WITH(READUNCOMMITTED) before closing the connection, it appears as expected.  However, upon closing the connection, the data disappears. Why isn't the transaction actually committing?

```
using (SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
    db.Open();
    SqlTransaction transaction = db.BeginTransaction("loadRate");
    try
    {
        int id = 0;
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("usp_1", db))
        {
            da.SelectCommand.Transaction = transaction;
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            id = (int)da.SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        int id2 = 0;
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("usp_2", db))
        {
            da.SelectCommand.Transaction = transaction;
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            id2 = (int)da.SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        }                    
        transaction.Commit();                    
        Console.WriteLine("Committed data");
    }
    catch (Exception insertExcept)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + insertExcept.Message + ".  Rolling Back");
        try
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {                      
            Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        db.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies - updated to be "db" as intended.

Comment: What do usp_1 and usp_2 look like? Can you simplify those as much as possible (perhaps just have them return an integer for testing purposes) and still reproduce the issue? If so, please include the procedure definitions in your question so that someone else may reproduce this on their machine easily. And just for the record, do you get "Committed data" message in the console? Do you get any message about a rollback in the console?

Comment: It may not be the problem (unless `SqlDataAdapter` does something funky) but there's absolutely no need to create a `SqlDataAdapter` just to execute an `INSERT` query. It may even get confused by setting the `SelectCommand` to an insert query. You might try just using a `SqlCommand` and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: I also have suspicions about SqlDataAdapter, but I couldn't find any reason why it would cause a problem.  I'll give it a shot.  @mason - I do indeed get the `Committed data` message in the console.  I get no exceptions or rollback text in the console. The stored procedures are a lot more complicated than what I have displayed; the first is a simple insert that returns the (int) unique key of the inserted row.  The second inserts a series of rows to a second table using the first key and a user defined Sql  table type, and returns the number of rows inserted.  Both work before the rollback.

Comment: I understand the sprocs are complicated. Make them not complicated. Make them simple, like `select 1` or whatever the TSQL equivalent is. Does the problem persist? Then the issue must be somewhere in the procedure, and you would need to narrow it down. Does changing it to `select 1` fix the issue? Then the issue is probably not in your stored procedure.

Comment: @DStanley - changing to SqlCommand did not change anything, unfortunately.  mason - the SPs will need to at least insert some data so that I can see if it worked, but I will simplify them as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @mason for pointing me in the right direction.  One of the stored procedures had an uncommitted transaction within it, and while .net's Commit could not close that transaction, closing the connection rolled it back automatically.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: You should include [MCVE] version of that stored procedure in your question.